# Will my credit score go down if I don’t borrow money for few years?

Tags: united-kingdom, credit-card, credit-score, credit-history

My credit score is relatively high. Due to personal circumstances I don’t intend to use my credit cards for the next 3 years. I won’t be getting any loans either. 
At the moment I have no debt at all, if my plan goes well hopefully it’ll stay like this till the beginning of 2022.

Will my credit score go down? 
I don’t mind if my credit accounts gets closed for not using them. I m interested in knowing about my credit score

Comment: will you still have any active loans such as for a car or mortgage? I know you said you won't be getting any loans, but will you have any existing ones?

Comment: @mhoran_psprep No. All have been paid

Comment: For the most part, credit scores are relevant only when you _apply_ for a loan which you say you don't plan on doing in the immediate future. There might be a _small_ issue if your credit cards get cancelled for lack of activity (if the cards charge an annual fee, they won't bother you at all!) and you want to apply for new ones ASAP, but otherwise, relax, stop obsessing about minor reductions in your credit score, and enjoy yourself.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why won't you use your CCs for a few years?  Many regulars on money.SE use them constantly, but don't carry a balance.

Answer (score 3):

Well usually credit score does depend on information regarding your payment history and debt ratio. Most scores tend to prefer someone with a low loan being paid perfectly in time than no loan payment history or credit card use at all. Having no action in your credit card shouldn't hurt your score much, however a benefit to not using it or taking any loans is that your debt/income ratio will improve (this means you have less debts, hence more money, hence more probability of successfully repaying a hypothetical loan). Of course each score has its own model and may vary according to each institution, but I doubt the action you are proposing will have any strong impact. You can always try and have a call with somebody within your institution that could you give suggestions on having a good credit score, that way you'll know the basic rules for your place.  Cheers

Comment: Since you mentioned debt to income ratio, I think it's important to point out that none of the major credit bureaus collect data about income, and none of the major credit scoring models include DTI in their credit score calculations.

Comment: They might not 'collect' data about income, but I'm pretty sure there's models to predict income, fixed and variable. I'm pretty sure they do since repayability has quite an interesting correlation to DTI (Not the credit, but in general for the customer).

Comment: For the scope of this question - regarding credit scores calculated by the currently popular credit score models (i.e. Vantagescore and FICO) there is no data about income or DTI used. In other words, if someone is asking about **credit score**, income is not part of the equation.

Comment: To nitpick: Banks do collect information about pay, but may for the time being be prevented by regulations from using it or passing it to referencing agencies in connection with credit scoring.

Comment: @dwizum VantageScore and FICO are not applicable in the UK.

Comment: @Vicky - credit scores in the UK do not include income either: https://www.moneyadviceservice.org.uk/en/articles/how-to-check-your-credit-report

Answer (score 2):

Your credit score is going to go down when you start using credit again.  You say you don't care if your accounts get closed but this does matter.  The problem is part of your credit rating is the age of your credit.

When you open new accounts you now have a very low credit age and that's not good.

You would be better served to keep a few cards alive.  You don't need to use them very often to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

If everything stays the same your credit score is going to go up, not down.

If credit cards get closed (especially older ones) because you're not using them the average age of your accounts is going to go down, which will make your credit score go down. If the accounts are newer than average your score will actually go up. However, your score will drop lower than it otherwise would have the next time you open an account (because the new account will be a higher percentage of all your accounts (1 in 10 rather than 1 in 20 for example)).

To answer the reason you asked the question: any changes to your credit report are going to be insignificant unless a significant number of your credit accounts get closed.

Answer (score 1):

Your "credit score" is a generic, indicative figure based on a credit reference agency's idea of what they think are good indicators for creditworthiness. Each of the CRA's will have their own algorithms for generating this score, so it will vary. 
These scores are not used by credit providers - they will have their own scoring criteria that varies from provider to provider. So the answer is not straightforward.

As a general rule, providers like to see a history of managing credit well when making lending decisions. No longer having a credit card that you pay off in full will not help in this regard, but may be mitigated to a certain extent by other aspects of your finances (current account overdraft available but not used, mobile phone contract paid on time, being on the electoral roll).